# How to calculate standard deviation using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, standard-deviation

I'm very new here,
at the moment I am trying to calculate standard deviation with Java (I have googled it haha)
but I am having a lot of issues on getting it working

I have ten values that are inputed by a user which I then have to calculate the standard deviation of 
my understanding so far thanks to people who have replied
is 
I find the mean of the array 
then complete the calculations

```
                double two = total[2];
                double three = total[3];
                double four = total[3];
                double five = total[4];
                double six = total[6];
                double seven = total[7];
                double eight = total[8];
                double nine = total[9];
                double ten = total[10];

                double eleven = average_total;


mean = one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten + eleven;

mean = mean/11;
//one = one - mean;
//System.out.println("I really hope this prints out a value:" +one);
*/
 //eleven = average_total - mean;
 //eleven = Math.pow(average_total,average_total);
 //stand_dev = (one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten + eleven);
 //stand_dev = stand_dev - mean;
// stand_dev = (stand_dev - mean) * (stand_dev - mean);
// stand_dev = (stand_dev/11);
// stand_dev = Math.sqrt(stand_dev);
```

I already have my data that is stored in an array of 10 values but I am not too sure
    how to print the data out of the array then do the calculations with out having to store the enter code here
    data some where else that I have manipulated

Thank you for your time, much appreciated :)

Comment: Show the code you have so far.

Comment: double one = total[1];
               
               
                double two = total[2];
                double three = total[3];
                double four = total[3];
                double five = total[4];
                double six = total[6];
                double seven = total[7];
                double eight = total[8];
                double nine = total[9];
                double ten = total[10];
                
                double eleven = average_total;

Comment: mean = one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten + eleven;

mean = mean/11;

 eleven = average_total - mean;
 eleven = Math.pow(average_total,average_total);
 stand_dev = (one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten + eleven);
 stand_dev = stand_dev - mean;
 stand_dev = (stand_dev - mean) * (stand_dev - mean);
 stand_dev = (stand_dev/11-1);
 stand_dev = Math.sqrt(stand_dev);

Comment: Sorry, that formated every so poorly

Comment: @TaylorGoodall Delete your comments. I've added the code to your question. Accept the edit and make sure your code is correct.

Comment: You slept through the lecture on loops, right?

Comment: So, what about your existing code doesn't work as you want? (I'm growing leery about this question considering the number of bad nonanswers it attracted.)

Comment: if you still having trouble you should check out my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  calculate mean of array.

  loop through values

       array value = (indexed value - mean)^2    

  calculate sum of the new array.

  divide the sum by the array length

  square root it
```

edited:

I'll show you how to loop through the array and everything is pretty much this same step just with a different calculation.

```
// calculating mean.

int total = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   total += array[i]; // this is the calculation for summing up all the values
}

double mean = total / array.length;
```

edit2:

After reading your code, the part you are doing wrong is that you are not looping through the values and subtracting it with average correctly.

aka this part.

> eleven = average_total - mean;
>   eleven = Math.pow(average_total,average_total);

you need to do this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   array[i] = Math.pow((array[i]-mean),2)
}
```

essentially you need to change every value in the array with newvalue =  oldvalue - mean(average).

then calculate the sum... then square root that.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at doing this, great advice :)

Comment: @prgenhard Thank you for all your input, it has helped a lot! I have cut out the old code, if i do it correctly I should be able to work it out a lot quicker with less lines of code here is what I have so far

Comment: for (int j = 1; j <= value; j++) {
                total[j] = (score1[j] * 0.1) + (score2[j] * 0.4) + (score3[j] * 0.2) + (score4[j] * 0.3);

Comment: Sorry, when I comment it formats it horriable, what I need to do is: go through the array, add the values together then divide by the number of values in the array ..that will get the mean and then I can work on what you said above? sorry if I don't seem up to date with it all

Comment: Arrays start 0 not one so when you do total[j] there will be a missing value at index 0. I would get in the habit of initializing at the array index of 0 (array[0]). Also, score1 is a single int so you can't have a j in there like that. Arrays are basically bunch of single ints (or whatever object you want) indexed in an entity. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array for more clarification and follow my example. Learning loops and arrays are super essential and once you get the understanding programming is alot less abstract.

Comment: Yeah that loop will calculate the sum of all the values in the array. Make sure you array is a double btw not an int. And initialize values like this array[0] = 34; or something like that.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Thank you once again, I understand they start at 0 (I don't mean that to sound rude) the only reason it starts at 1 is because I have to enter users like user1 and the int on the end comes from that value my tutor said it's an easy fix but I still lack a lot of the logic fundementals at this moment, but im learning :)

Comment: accepted the answer if helped you :)

Answer (score 15):

There is a simple formula that can be used to quickly calculate standard deviation every time a number is added. Here is some code that implements that formula, assuming `total[]` has been declared and populated already:

```
double powerSum1 = 0;
double powerSum2 = 0;
double stdev = 0;

for i = 0 to total.length {
    powerSum1 += total[i];
    powerSum2 += Math.pow(total[i], 2);
    stdev = Math.sqrt(i*powerSum2 - Math.pow(powerSum1, 2))/i;
    System.out.println(total[i]); // You specified that you needed to print 
                                  // each value of the array
}
System.out.println(stdev); // This could also be placed inside the loop 
                           // for updates with each array value.
```

The beauty of this formula is that you don't have to reprocess the entire array each time you add a new value and you don't have to store any of the old values of the array, just the three variables declared in the code above.

Comment: This is very simple and easy to understand ! thank you, I am getting an error with the for loop though apart from that thank you very much!

Comment: I hadn't actually compiled and ran the code, just wrote it out as an example of the concept. Were you able to work out the problem? If so, please feel free to edit the post to show what the corrected code would be. Also, up votes are always welcome!

Comment: A warning on use of the above method - it is prone to greater errors in accuracy due to compounding floating point errors.

Answer (score 2):

I won't solve your problem for you since this looks like howework, but I'll try to help you out a little by giving you some pseudocode to point you in the right direction:

```
Loop over array i=1 to 10
    Add each element to some other variable Total
End of Loop

Average = Total / 10 (required for your std. dev. equation)
```

Now you need to find the distances of the elements from the mean. Easy

```
Loop over array i = 1 to 10
    Replace each element with its distance from Average Squared
    Add to some variable differenceTotal
End of Loop
```

Then you have your numerator and denominator terms, and your solution should be obvious. Hopefully that was somewhat clear and helpful.

Comment: Thank you! that makes it a bit more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class StandardDeviationCalc {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double [] values = {9, 2, 5, 4, 12, 7, 8, 11, 9, 3, 7, 4, 12, 5, 4, 10,
                            9, 6, 9, 4 };   //change input values here
        double sum=0;
        double finalsum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for( double i : values) {
            finalsum = (sum += i);
        }

        average = finalsum/(values.length);
        System.out.println("Average: "+ average);

        double sumX=0;
        double finalsumX=0;
        double[] x1_average = new double[2000];
        for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
            double fvalue = (Math.pow((values[i] - average), 2));
            x1_average[i]= fvalue;
            System.out.println("test: "+ fvalue);
        }

        for(double i : x1_average) {
            finalsumX = (sumX += i);
        }

        Double AverageX = finalsumX/(values.length);
        System.out.println("E(X1-x1_average)^2/AverageX: "+ AverageX);
        double SquareRoot = Math.sqrt(AverageX);
        System.out.println("Standard Deviation: "+ SquareRoot);
    }
}
```

You can tweak to how u want like adding user input.The code is rough becose I assume this is a homework. try to make it nice in your own way. hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?...

You will need to loop the values for example to print all the values

```
for(int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++)
{
     System.out.println(yourArray[i]);
     // Add your code to calculate the values you need for standard dev
}
```

Comment: I have tried manually assigning the array values to variables and then manually writing out the equasion but I am not getting anywhere near the results, tried to edit/post the code but was having issues

Comment: Make sure you are using `double` and not `int` for any divisions you are doing other wise you will be getting rounding errors