# Loops With Multiple Variables

Tags: java, loops, statistics, logic

I want my program to calculate values from x = -2.0 to x = 2.0. I also want it to do that for value of the standard deviation from -3.0 to 3.0. There should be a total of 140 outputs arranged in a table. I am having trouble however, getting the standard deviation values to change. Everything I have tried so far just outputs x at one set of standard deviations. How can I modify the outer loop to perform the run again through x and maintain all outputs? Here is what I've come up with so far, but without any success:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class STable {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    double exponent,  x, pi, e, sqrtpart, y, stnrd, mean;

    mean = 0;
    stnrd = -3.0;
    pi = 3.14159;
    e = 2.71828;
    x = -2.0;
    int count = 0;
    int supercount = 0;

    while (supercount < 140)
    {   
        while (count < 20)
        {
            exponent = - ((x-mean)*(x-mean)/(2.0*stnrd));
            sqrtpart = Math.sqrt(2*pi);
            y = (Math.pow(e,exponent))/sqrtpart;

            System.out.print(" " + y);
            x = x + 0.2;
            count++;
        }

        x=-2.0;
        System.out.println("\n");

        stnrd = stnrd + 1.0;    
        supercount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the bracket edit a solution, or just a correction? (are you still having the problem?)

Comment: This a standard deviation i did a while back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390548/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation-using-java/18391710#18391710

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to reset your `count` variable after each inner loop. Otherwise on all subsequent passes of the outer loop, `count` will still be 20, so the inner loop won't execute.

Second, I don't think the outer loop is applied to everything because you didn't use brackets to declare its scope.

When I slightly modify your code to be:

```
public class STable {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {


        double exponent,  x, pi, e, sqrtpart, y, stnrd, mean;

        mean = 0;
        stnrd = -3.0;
        pi = 3.14159;
        e = 2.71828;
        x = -2.0;
        int count = 0;
        int supercount = 0;

        while (supercount < 140) {



        while (count < 20)
        {

            exponent = - ((x-mean)*(x-mean)/(2.0*stnrd));

            sqrtpart = Math.sqrt(2*pi);


        y = (Math.pow(e,exponent))/sqrtpart;

        System.out.print(" " + y);
        x = x + 0.2;
        count++;
        }

        x=-2.0;
        count = 0;
        System.out.println("\n");

        stnrd = stnrd + 1.0;    
        supercount++;




        }
    }
}
```

I get the output I believe you're looking for.

As a side note, this is a good use case for a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to avoid mistakes due to forgetting to reset counting variables. :)

Edit - for loop version with proper loop execution count:

```
public class STable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double exponent, pi, e, sqrtpart, y, mean;

        mean = 0;
        pi = 3.14159;
        e = 2.71828;
        for (double stnrd = -3.0; stnrd <= 3.0; stnrd += 1) {
            double x = -2.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
                exponent = -((x - mean) * (x - mean) / (2.0 * stnrd));

                sqrtpart = Math.sqrt(2 * pi);

                y = (Math.pow(e, exponent)) / sqrtpart;

                System.out.print(" " + y);
                x += 0.2;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I updated the inner loop to run 21 times, as there are 21 inclusive 0.2 steps from -2.0 to 2.0.

Comment: Yes that seemed to work although I'm not sure if the output is correct

Comment: Yes, `supercount` is being incremented in the wrong spot. As is, the outer loop will execute 140 times, for a total of 2800 inner loop executions. Move the `supercount++` to the inner loop, to ensure 140 total executions, and see if the output is closer to what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me what you're trying to do, but you should wrap every loop in braces, i.e.
    `while` (*cond*) { *body* }

Notice that your first `while` loop doesn't have any braces wrapping its body, meaning your code is effectively the same as

```
while(supercount < 140)
{
    while (count < 20)
    {
        ...
    }
}

x=-2.0;
System.out.println("\n");

stnrd = stnrd + 1.0;    
supercount++;
```

I'm guessing you want that last part within the first `while` loop's body.