# Calculating and printing the Standard Deviation of a user-defined Array

Tags: arrays, eclipse, standard-deviation

My program takes an array of numbers from the user and calculates those numbers into the mean and into the standard deviation. I'm having an issue with my Standard Deviation part and I'm not sure if I'm even doing this correctly. Here is what I have:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to calculate?");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    double a[] = new double[(int) n]; // casting n to a double
    double sum = 0.0;
    double sd = 0.0;
    int ifLoop = 0;

    System.out.println("Fill in the values for all " + n + " numbers.");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        sum = sum + a[i];
        ifLoop++;

        if(ifLoop == a.length)
        {
            sd = sd + Math.pow(a[i] - (sum/a.length), 2);       //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The Mean of the " + n +" numbers is " + sum/a.length);              // this line finds the average
    System.out.println("The Standard Deviation of the " + n + " numbers is " + sd);
}
```

Example input:
30.7
190.9
11
14
Output:
The Mean of the 4 numbers is 61.65
The Standard Deviation of the 4 numbers is 2270.5225 I know this is wrong because the 2270.5225 is bogus and I'm not sure how to correctly implement the Standard Deviation formula. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link. You can get the answer for your query.

[How to calculate standard deviation using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390548/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to calculate the Standard deviation after input all the number to array. You have to calculate **mean** first. After that SD. Have to use 2 loops.

```
double calculateSD(double[] values) {
    double mean = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    int n = values.length;
    for (double value : values) {
        sum += value;
    }
    mean = sum / n;
    sum = 0.0;
    for (double value : values) {
        sum += Math.pow(mean - value, 2);
    }
    return sum / n;
}
```