# Getting Java methods from one object and a constructor from another object

Tags: java

I have three class `Homework` that has my `main(...)`, `GradeArray`, which has my methods, and `StudentGrade`, which has my constructor.

Currently , which is clearly wrong, I have in Homework:

GradeArray grades = new GradeArray();`

In GradeArray at the top I have `StudentGrade[]  ArrayGrades = new StudentGrade[size];` however this method did not give me both the contructor and the methods. I know I don't need three classes for this but my professor wants three class. How do I declare an array that has attributes from two classes so that I can get the methods from GradeArray and the constructor from `StudentGrade`?

Thank you for you time and help.

Here is all of my code

package homework1;

```
public class Homework1
{  
   public static int pubSize;
   public static String pubCourseID;

   public static void makeVarsPub(int maxSize, String courseID)  //this is to makes the varibles public
   {
     pubSize = maxSize;

     pubCourseID = courseID;
   }
  public int giveSize()
  {
    return pubSize;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     int maxSize = 100;    
     String courseID = "CS116";
     //this is to makes the varibles public

     makeVarsPub(maxSize, courseID);

     StudentGrade grades = new StudentGrade();

     grades.insert("Evans", 78, courseID);
     grades.insert("Smith", 77, courseID);
     grades.insert("Yee", 83, courseID);
     grades.insert("Adams", 63, courseID);
     grades.insert("Hashimoto", 91, courseID);
     grades.insert("Stimson", 89, courseID);
     grades.insert("Velasquez", 72, courseID);
     grades.insert("Lamarque", 74, courseID);
     grades.insert("Vang", 52, courseID);
     grades.insert("Creswell", 88, courseID);

     // print grade summary: course ID, average, how many A, B, C, D and Fs
     System.out.println(grades);   

     String searchKey = "Stimson";  // search for item
     String found = grades.find(searchKey);
     if (found != null) {
        System.out.print("Found ");
        System.out.print(found);
     }
     else
        System.out.println("Can't find " + searchKey);

     // Find average and standard deviation
     System.out.println("Grade Average: " + grades.avg());
     System.out.println("Standard dev;  " + grades.std());

     // Show student grades sorted by name and sorted by grade
     grades.reportGrades();     // sorted by name  
     grades.reportGradesSorted();       // sorted by grade

     System.out.println("Deleting Smith, Yee, and Creswell");
     grades.delete("Smith");           // delete 3 items
     grades.delete("Yee");
     grades.delete("Creswell");

     System.out.println(grades);    // display the course summary again


   }//end of Main

 }//end of homework1




package homework1;

class GradeArray
{
  int nElems = 0; //keeping track of the number of entires in the array.
  Homework1 homework1InfoCall = new Homework1();  //this is so I can get the information I need.
  int size = homework1InfoCall.giveSize();


  StudentGrade[]  ArrayGrades = new StudentGrade[size];


   public String ToString(String name, int score, String courseID)
   {

       String res = "Name: " + name + "\n";
       res += "Score: " + score + "\n";
       res += "CourseID " + courseID + "\n";
       return res;
   }

   public String getName(int num) //returns name based on array location.
   {
      return ArrayGrades[num].name;
   }  

   public double getScore(int num)  //returns score based on array location.
   {
      return ArrayGrades[num].score;
   }  

   public void insert(String name, double score, String courseID)  //part of the insert method is going to be
           //taken from lab one and modified to fit the need.
   {
     if(nElems == size){
          System.out.println("Array is full");
          System.out.println("Please delete an Item before trying to add more");
          System.out.println("");
        }
      else{
        ArrayGrades[nElems].name = name;
        ArrayGrades[nElems].score = score;            
        ArrayGrades[nElems].courseID = courseID;
        nElems++;                      // increment the number of elements

       };
   }

   public void delete(String name) //code partly taken from lab1
   {
     int j;
     for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)        // look for it
        if( name == ArrayGrades[j].name)
           break;
     if(j>nElems)                  // can't find it
     {
        System.out.println("Item not found");
     }
     else                           // found it
     {
       for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++) // move higher ones down
        {
            boolean go = true;
            if ((k+2)>size)
                go = false;
            if(go)
                ArrayGrades[k] = ArrayGrades[k+1];
         }
            nElems--;                   // decrement size
            System.out.println("success");

         }
   }


   public String find (String name){ //code partly taken from lab1
      int j;

      for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)            // for each element,
         if(ArrayGrades[j].name == name)        // found item?
            break;                       // exit loop before end
      if(j == nElems)                    // gone to end?
         return null;                   // yes, can't find it
      else
         return ArrayGrades[j].toString();

   }

   public double avg() //this is to get the average
   {
      double total = 0;
      for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)
          total += ArrayGrades[j].score;

      total /= nElems;

      return total;
   }

   public double std() //this is to get the standard deviation. Information on Standard deviation derived from
           //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390548/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation-using-java
   {  
       double mean = 0; //this is to hold the mean
       double newSum = 0;
       for(int j=0; j < ArrayGrades.length; j++) //this is to get the mean.
           mean =+ ArrayGrades[j].score;
       for(int i=0; i < ArrayGrades.length; i++)  //this is to get the new sum.
           newSum =+ (ArrayGrades[i].score - mean);
       mean = newSum/ArrayGrades.length;  //this is to get the final answer for the mean.

       return mean;
   }

   public StudentGrade[] reportGrades()  //this is grade sorted by name
   {

     int in,out;
     char compair;  //this is for compairsons.
     StudentGrade temp; //this is to hold the orginal variable.
     //for the first letter cycle
     for(out=1; out<ArrayGrades.length; out++)
     {
       temp =  ArrayGrades[out];
       compair= ArrayGrades[out].name.charAt(0);  
       in=out;
       while(in>0 && ArrayGrades[in-1].name.charAt(0) > compair)
       {
         ArrayGrades[in] = ArrayGrades[in-1];
         in--;
       }
       ArrayGrades[in]=temp;
     }

     //this is for the second run.
     for(out=1; out<ArrayGrades.length; out++)
     {
       temp = ArrayGrades[out];
       compair= ArrayGrades[out].name.charAt(1);  
       in=out;
       while(in>0 && ArrayGrades[in-1].name.charAt(1) > compair)
       {
         ArrayGrades[in] = ArrayGrades[in-1];
         in--;
       }
       ArrayGrades[in]=temp;
     }    

     return ArrayGrades;
   }

   public StudentGrade[] reportGradesSorted() //this is grades sorted by grades.
           //this is grabbed from lab2 and repurposed.
   {
     int in,out;
     double temp;
     for(out=1; out<ArrayGrades.length; out++)
     {
       temp=ArrayGrades[out].score;  
       in=out;
       while(in>0 && ArrayGrades[in-1].score>=temp)
       {
         ArrayGrades[in]= ArrayGrades[in-1];
         in--;
       }
       ArrayGrades[in].score=temp;
   }
     return ArrayGrades;
} //end of GradeArray


package homework1;


public class StudentGrade extends GradeArray
{
   public String name;
   double score;
   public String courseID;



   public void StudentGrade (String name, double score, String courseID)  //this is the constructor
   {                              
      this.name = name;
      this.score = score;
      this.courseID = courseID;
   }


}//end of StudentGrade class.
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: I think it will be better go to your professor and clarify with him all the details.

Comment: Each of the 3 classes will have a constructor that is unique to that type.  Each of the 3 classes will have methods and data (members) unique to those types.

Comment: Sure. You don't "declare an array that has attributes", you create an array and populate it with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I feel @Alexandr has the best answer.  Talk with your professor.

Your question doesn't make it quite clear what you need.  However, it sounds like basic understanding of inheritance and class construction would get you going on the right path.   Each of the 3 classes will have a constructor that is unique to that type. Each of the 3 classes will have methods and data (members) unique to those types.

Below is just a quick example of what I threw together.  I have strong concerns that my answer is actually what your professor is looking for however--it is not an object model I would suggest--just an example.

```
public class Homework {
    private String student;
    public Homework(String name) {
        student = name;
    }
    public String getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
}

public class StudentGrade extends Homework {
    private String grade;
    public StudentGrade(String grade, String name) {
        super(name);

        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

}

public class HomeworkGrades {
    public List<StudentGrade> getGrades() {
         // this method isnt implemented but should
         // be finished to return array of grades
    }
}
```

Take a look and see if that helps you understand something about inheritance and class construction.

Hopefully you can infer a bit about inheritence (StudentGrade inherits -- in java extends -- from HomeWork) and class construction.

Thnx
Matt

Comment: I will admit I don't understand inheritance and our class is just covering sorting so I don't think it will be covered any time soon which is why I don't understand why he wants 3 classes. I added the code at the time, which I should have done in the first place. on StudentGrade I added extends GradeArray and that does do what I need it to. I still need to figure out why it isn't making the array correctly but this does do what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I change the array creation in Homework1 to be `StudentGrade grades = new StudentGrade();` and I added `extends GradeArray` to the StudentGrade class. it is now  `public class StudentGrade extends GradeArray`.